# fb oAuth and reading close group feed - probm

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-oauth

We are in a big trouble please help.

When group was open, we could read the JSON feed, but when group privacy is set to "Closed" we cannot read it, and we cannot turn group back to "Open". What we are doing right now is

`$facebook = new Facebook(
    array(
      'appId'  => '',
      'secret' => '',
    )
);`

$t= $facebook->getAccessToken();
$gid = "233395776824135"; # some group id

$data = curl_get("https://graph.facebook.com/$gid/feed?limit=20&access_token=$t");
curl_get is a function that reads using curl

Now the data returned to us is (all the time) only 
**{ "data": [ ] }**

is there anything we need to do to "getAccessToken" function of oAuth to set user_groups permission? if yes HOW can we do that?

Following page tells that if group is closed you need user_groups permission
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group/

Please help! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different access tokens in Facebook. For a public group, you can just use an "app access token", i guess that´s what you got with the call to "getAccessToken" (it´s basically static for every app and a combination of app id and app secret. For non-public groups you need a "user access token", which means that you have to implement a user login (with the user_groups permission). See here for the documentation to use login with the JavaScript API:

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/

User access tokens are only valid for 2 hours btw, you can extend them to 60 days by calling the "setExtendedAccessToken" of the PHP SDK. That means, you cannot use this to publish the feed of a non-public group on your own website, you can only present it to one user. Or you store the user token and refresh it every 60 days. But i would not recommend this, makes the non-public setting of the group void and the admin might not like it.

Comment: I myself am an Admin of the group sir, and since group is not open anymore I cant fetch the feed. Secondly do you mean by sending temporary token to "setExtendedAccessToken" will make it be used for 60 days or something ?

Comment: yes, that function extends a token for up to 60 days (instead of the default 2 hours). and you do need a user token for the feed of a non-public group, which is only logical because only a member of the group is allowed to read it.

so, your only chance is what i have written: user login with user_groups permission will do it.